# Ubuntu 22.04.01 shuts down after closing lid

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, systemd, systemd-logind

My Ubuntu 22.04.01 (dual booted along with windows on my HP laptop) keeps shutting down when I close the lid. I tried some ways of preventing this, like modifying the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file, checking power settings and using Tweaks. But none of them worked. My laptop still shuts down after closing the lid every time.
Here is my config file just in case:

```````
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#UserStopDelaySec=10
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#HandleRebootKey=reboot
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#RebootKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RuntimeDirectoryInodesMax=400k
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192``````
```````

[Screenshot of Tweaks gnome general settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfTOm.png)

Please help me guys!

Comment: have you run `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` since you changed the configuration file? Although I guess if it restarts each time you close the lid so eventually it should work. Also what does `sudo systemctl hibernate` do? Does it send your laptop to sleep or just shut it down?

Comment: @RobertLongson I just tried ```sudo systemctl hibernate``` . It shut down my laptop.

Comment: @RobertLongson I went through the link you sent. I see references to a script sleep.sh in  /etc/acpi/ . I wanted to see what that script does and checked /etc/acpi to realize that /etc/acpi doesn't contain a sleep.sh file! Do you think that's causing a problem or it's just somewhere else

Comment: @RobertLongson "hibernate" is supposed to shut down. The OP is talking about suspension which is quite different.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue in 22.04. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Ensei_Tankado No, I found nothing useful. I gave up after sometime and got used to the problem. But a few months ago I had to reinstall Ubuntu because of some unrelated issues. Somehow, this problem fixed itself after that. I am clueless as to why this happened.